# Propuesta para cambiar la etiqueta "drae" por "dle"

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas

Desde 1925, el diccionario de la RAE se titula *Diccionario de la lengua española*, abreviado DLE. Y de hecho, la propia RAE se refiere a su obra como el DLE, sobre todo [en medios como Twitter](https://twitter.com/search?q=from%3ARAEinforma%20DLE&src=typd) en los que el espacio es vital.

En el sitio tenemos la etiqueta [drae](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drae) para las preguntas que tienen que ver de alguna forma con dicho diccionario de la RAE. En aras de la precisión y la corrección, ¿deberíamos renombrar la etiqueta para que pase a ser [dle](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dle)?

Answer (score 2):

Yo creo que sí.

En [Diccionario de la lengua española, claves de redacción](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/diccionario-de-la-lengua-espanola-claves-de-redaccion/), Fundéu dice:

> DRAE, de Diccionario de la Real Academia Española, es la sigla asentada entre los hablantes para referirse a esta obra, aunque no sea el nombre oficial del diccionario. La sigla correspondiente al nombre real es DLE.

Es decir, lo natural es escribir DRAE y lo correcto es DLE. Dado que lo que haríamos es crear un sinónimo, cuando uno escribiera DRAE le recomendaría DLE. Lo que habría que hacer, pues, es poner un buen *excerpt* en la [descripción de la etiqueta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags/drae/info) para que fuera claro para el usuario que nos estamos refiriendo a lo mismo.

---

He procedido a realizar el cambio.

[dle](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dle) ahora contiene el siguiente extracto:

> Preguntas sobre el Diccionario de la lengua española de la RAE (oficialmente DLE, también conocido como DRAE), la obra sobre el idioma español más autoritaria // Questions about the Diccionario de la lengua española de la RAE (officially DLE and also known as DRAE), the most authoritative dictionary of the Spanish language.

Comment: Si la respuesta tiene buena acogida, en unos días podemos crear el sinónimo.

Comment: Pasados unos días, procedo.